# Hibernate cascade child objects does not store ID of parent table in lookup table

Tags: java, mysql, entity-framework, hibernate, jpa

I have a table A and table C. Relationship between A - C is 1 - * and for this reason i have a lookup table B.
B which stores the 'id' of A and 'id' of 'C'.

**Entities:**

```
Class A {
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "A", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   private List<B> b;
}

Class B {
   @ManyToOne
   private A a;

   @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumn(name = "id")
   private C c;
}

Class C {
   @OneToOne(mappedBy = "c")
   private B b;
}
```

I have defined CASCADE ALL in class A and class B, which means that when I persist an entity of class A I want to persist all entities of class B AND when I persist an entity of class B I want to persist all entities of class C.

**Save operation:**

```
A a = new A();
B b = someMethodToGetB(); 
A.setB(B);
save(A);

someMethodToGetB() {
C c = new C();
b.setC(c);
return b;
}
```

**Problem:**
All entries are made in table 'C'.
All entries are made in table 'A'.
But all entries in table 'B' (lookup table) have the ID of class 'A' as null.

How does the save operation with CASCADE work? In my case i first want entries in table C and A to be made. And for each of the entries there should be an entry in the lookup table. Is this possible to achieve in some way using CASCADE or do i need to manually create entities for A and C, and then get the IDs and save in B?

Can anyone please point out what am I doing wrong or missing?

Answer (score 0):

> I have defined CASCADE ALL in class A and class B, which means that
>   when I persist an entity of class A I want to persist all entities of
>   class B AND when I persist an entity of class B I want to persist all
>   entities of class C.

Hibernate doesn't work in this way.
When you persist, the persist on cascade on relationships is applied if you persist the owner entity of the relationship.
In your case, the owner is B according to the `mappedby` values you use.
So, you should persist B with all relationship set as you need.

```
A a = new A();
B b = someMethodToGetB(); 
A.setB(B);
save(A);

someMethodToGetB() {
  C c = new C();
  b.setC(c);
  return b;
}
```

should be :

```
B b = someMethodToGetB(); 
A a = new A();  
b.setA(a);
save(b);

someMethodToGetB() {
  B b = new B();
  C c = new C();
  b.setC(c);
  return b;
}
```

I have corrected the typo in your pseudo code.